# Can't save profile on my dev org

Tags: profile, permission-sets

When I try to save profile on my dev org I see the error:

> Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

I added Subscribe to Dashboards, Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients, Subscribe to Reports and Subscribe to Reports: Add Recipients. But still I can't save my profile. I worked before 100%.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which profile is that? I have logged a case for similar issue with admin profile recently

Comment: Is it happening via UI or API? And like @kurunve asked, which profile?

Comment: It's standard System admin profile and UI.

Comment: Like and Share -- https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AU7mQAG

Answer (score 0):

Seems a something wrong from Salesforce side.

**Workaround:**

```
1) Go to Manage Users --> User Management Settings 
2) Enable the Enhanced Profile User Interface setting 
3) Go back to the Profile which you want to update 
4) Profile Saved successfully.
```

It's worked for me as well.